# Configure Yii to generate CRUD(Gii) in themes folder

Tags: php, yii, gii

In a Yii project I have the structure:

```
project/
    ... default Yii structure here ...
themes/
    css/
    font/
    images/
    js/
    views/
        admin/
        layouts/
        site/
```

How to configure Gii to generate CRUD in themes folder?

Comment: bad idea, if you want to generate the controller and views under themes; the controller needs to be protected

Comment: not to mention that the modules cient/admin wont work

Comment: Crud is crud, themes are themes. They are like wrappers or skins. Read more here http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/topics.theming

Comment: I'm newbie in Yii. Still do not understand what are CRUD in Yii. If we have a MVC and themes, because we have a generation of CRUD?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian I do not want to generate controllers, etc.. in themes. I want to generate only views in themes.

Comment: let gii to generate them where he wants, then set the theme as needed, then move the view files in the theme folders so that the path is the same as a standard path; the controller should search for the view files in the standard place and then in the theme folders

Comment: It's exactly what I'm having to do. But manually move was not what I wanted.